# Android service timer not stopping

Tags: android, timer

I am having a problem with a timer in Android service.
So i have put public static for the timer, on destroy i am canceling and purging the timers.

The problem i am facing is that only 1 of the 2 timers, do not stop, and i can not figure out why.

here is part of the code:

```
private static Timer t,t1; @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Test Service","Service desroyed");
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Destroy",1).show();
    sendMessage("Stop Audio");
    t.cancel();
    t.purge();
    t1.cancel();
    t1.purge();
    super.onDestroy();
}

  @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
        t = new Timer();
        t1 = new Timer();
if(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == pm.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,foregroundappPackageInfo.packageName)){

            final int interval = 15000; // 15 Second

            t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Boolean temp = validateMicAvailability();

                    if(temp) {

                        isStarted = true;
                        sendMessage("Start Audio");
                        t1.cancel();
                        t1.purge();

                    }else{

                        if(isStarted) {
                            t1.cancel();
                            t1.purge();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },30000,interval);
        }else {

            isStarted=true;
            sendMessage("Start Audio");

            final int interval = 2000; // 2 Second
            t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) TestService.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
                        String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName();
                        PackageManager pm = TestService.this.getPackageManager();
                        PackageInfo foregroundappPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);
                        String foregroundTaskAppName = foregroundappPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();

                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 22 ) {
                            if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == pm.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, getForegroundApp().replaceAll("\u0000",""))) {

                                    Log.d("Test Service", "Stoping audio if audio permision app in front API22");
                                    if (isStarted) {
                                        isStarted = false;
                                        sendMessage("Stop Audio");
                                    }

                            } else {
                                if (!isStarted) {
                                    isStarted = true;
                                    sendMessage("Start Audio");
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == pm.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, foregroundappPackageInfo.packageName)) {
                                if (foregroundTaskAppName == "ALLeVIEW SCAN") {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "HERE IF ALLEVIEW IS IN FRONT");
                                    t.cancel();
                                    t.purge();
                                } else {

                                    Log.d("Test Service", "Stoping audio if audio permision app in front API <22");
                                    if (isStarted) {
                                        isStarted = false;
                                        sendMessage("Stop Audio");
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (!isStarted) {
                                    isStarted = true;
                                    sendMessage("Start Audio");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){};
                }
                },0,interval);
 }

    }catch(Exception e){};
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Working", 1).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

So the timer t1, i am having difficulties stopping it. When i debug the app, i see it is executing t1.cancel() and t1.purge(), but the timer continues to run, i can see the log displaying  Log.d(TAG,"Audio still taken incoming call "); and i see that isStarted is true. Also, when the service is destroyed from my main activity, the timer t1 doesnt cancel either.

I have tried also setting t1=null, but that doesnt help either.

I am starting the service from the onPause method in my main activity, and canceling the service onResume inside the main activity.

Any ideas what to try? why t1 timer doesnt want to stop? the timer t stops when the service is destroyed, which is the only way to stop Timer t.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: "I am starting the service from the onPause method in my main activity, and canceling the service onResume inside the main activity" -- then what purpose is there in having the service at all? Why not use `ScheduledExecutorService` from inside the main activity?

Comment: well i use the onPause and onResume, since i need the service started running when the app goes in background, and when it comes out of background, to cancel the service. 

From what i read regarding ScheduledExecutorService, i dont need to schedule the start of the service, it just needs to run when the app is in the background.

Comment: "well i use the onPause and onResume" -- oops, sorry, I had it backwards. I thought you were only using the service while your app was in the foreground. My apologies! "it just needs to run when the app is in the background" -- I would still use `ScheduledExecutorService` in your `Service`, instead of `Timer`, and definitely instead of two separate `Timer` objects.

Comment: well i had it setup as 1 timer, but still didnt work, and then i tried using 2 separate timers, and again didnt work. but what will ScheduledExecutorService help me with? isnt that for start service?

Comment: "but what will ScheduledExecutorService help me with?" -- it is a more modern replacement for `Timer`. It is from standard Java; despite the name, it is not tied to Android's concept of a service.

Comment: ooo ok, i will take a look at it then, and try to implement that and test it today

Comment: thanks CommonsWare, that worked out. Thanks for the help